# Turn off compatibility view for particular subsite - it was set in group policy

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, group-policy

In my machine compatibility view is forced by group policy. So some of the code is not working. Is it possible to disable compatibility view for a particular site/page somehow? I mean through web.config or any other setting in the front end server or the machine where the site is being viewed?

Tried setting meta tag, those are ignored as the compatibility view is forced by GP.

Comment: Do you mean you are adding the compatibility view via the GP "Use Policy List of Windows Internet Explorer 7 sites" key?If that is the case, from [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/group-policy-compatibility-with-ie11), it won’t be able to remove the sites you specifically added. I suggest you could consider to use registry to manage the IE compatibility view. Try to open registry and navigate to `Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\BrowserEmulation\\ClearableListData`, then check the UserFilter key value, it contains the compatibility list.

Comment: Yes, correct. It was added through Use Policy List of Windows Internet Explorer 7 Sites. We can't tell admin to modify group policy, so will just tell them there is no way to avoid compatibility view once group policy is enabled for the domain. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

try adding X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge as Response Header

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
           <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```